# R - Manipulating columns in a data.frame to eliminate censored values by converting characters to numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is a mini version of the data I am working with:

```
columnNum <- c("G1", "G2", "G3")
Al <- c("<5", 6, 7, "<4", 5, 6)
Ca <- c(9, 10, 11,10, 11, 12)
df <- data.frame(columnNum, Al, Ca, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Currently the classes of each column are character, character, numeric (in order, left to right) due to some of the values being censored (containing "<")

What I am trying to do is replace the values in the "Al" column with the actual numeric values instead of strings. I'm sure I could find a way to do it for just one column but my problem is that, in reality, I have 20 different columns, not 2.  I need to go through each column (from column "Al" to "Zn"), checking to see if the values are censored and if so, get rid of "<" and convert it to a number.

I'm still pretty new so this is what I tried to do (on my big data, not this little one):

```
for(i in df$Al:df$Zn)
{
   if (class(df[[i]]) != numeric)
   {
      df[[i]] <-  as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "<", replacement =    
      "", df[[i]])) 
   }
}
```

The loop just never ends.

Comment: `df$Al:df$Zn` is not a sequence of column indices, it's a sequence from the first element of `df$Al` to the first element of `df$Zn` (if they're numeric).

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I just took a shot in the dark to see what would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should first locate the columns that will be adjusted. We do this according to your description as the columns from `Al` to `Zn`. Next we `sub` unnecessary characters and convert to `numeric` with the `numerize` function. I added more columns to show the complexity:

```
cols <- match("Al", names(df)):match("Zn", names(df))
numerize <- function(x) as.numeric(sub(".*?([0-9.-]+).*", "\\1", x))

#base R
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], numerize)

#dplyr
df %>% mutate_at(vars(Al:Zn), numerize)

#data.table
setDT(df)[, (names(df)[cols]) := lapply(.SD, numerize), .SDcols=cols][]

#   columnNum Al Yw Zn Ca
# 1        G1  5  8  1  9
# 2        G2  6  6  6 10
# 3        G3  7  7  7 11
# 4        G1  4  4  4 10
# 5        G2  5  5  5 11
# 6        G3  6  6  6 12
```

**Data**

```
columnNum <- c("G1", "G2", "G3")
Al <- c("<5", 6, 7, "<4", 5, 6)
Yw <- c("<8", 6, 7, "<4", 5, 6)
Zn <- c("<1", 6, 7, "<4", 5, 6)
Ca <- c(9, 10, 11,10, 11, 12)
df <- data.frame(columnNum, Al, Yw, Zn, Ca, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::extract_numeric` is handy, whether in `dplyr` or not:

```
df$Al <- tidyr::extract_numeric(Al)    # or df %>% mutate(Al = extract_numeric(Al))
```

which is roughly equivalent to

```
df$Al <- as.numeric(sub('.*(-?[0-9]+.?[0-9]*).*', '\\1', df$Al))
```

which for this particular case could be simplified to:

```
df$Al <- as.integer(sub('<', '', df$Al))
```

Regardless of which you use, for this data you get:

```
##   columnNum Al Ca
## 1        G1  5  9
## 2        G2  6 10
## 3        G3  7 11
## 4        G1  4 10
## 5        G2  5 11
## 6        G3  6 12
```